# How to force SQL Reporting Service to user HTTP

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a silent installation of SQL 2008 ( with a ini configuration file).
The problem is is I have a SSL certificate on local IIS the Reporting Service automatically sets SecureConnectionLevel to 2 ( HTTPS ) so each time I need to change it manually to 0 ( HTTP ).

How could I force Reporting service to ignore SSL?(I don;t want to change it manually each time)
Is it possible via  configuration ini?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use Reporting Services Configuration Manager?

If not, open the RSCM and connect to your server, and then go to Web Service URL tab. After that, you choose the "(Not Selected)"  from the SSL Certificate combo box, then click apply.

This should resolve your issue.

Cheers.